# Truffle does nothing and shows no output when running tests

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am switching machines and ran into a weird issue with truffle.  Truffle is set up properly on my old machine.  I can compile and run tests without any issues.  To my knowledge, I set up everything the same way on my new machine.  All tests and source files were pulled from a repo, so I at least know my project directory is identical on both machines.

When I attempt to run tests on my new machine via `truffle test`, the console hangs for about ten seconds, then the terminal prompt reappears:

`benjamin@spectre-laptop:~/git/busd/ethereum$ truffle test
benjamin@spectre-laptop:~/git/busd/ethereum$`

I do not receive any output or errors.  This also occurs with `truffle deploy` and `truffle compile`.

If I run truffle build, I see the following:

`benjamin@spectre-laptop:~/git/busd/ethereum$ truffle build
No build configuration found. Preparing to compile contracts.
benjamin@spectre-laptop:~/git/busd/ethereum$`

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Check your Truffle version on each machine, and get back to us with your findings.

Comment: 5.0.2 on my old machine, 5.0.3 on my new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing exactly the same error 
i had installed truffle before so when i checked the version..it was all compatible.
But you need to do:
npm i -g truffle
add sudo in the beginning due to permissions.
and the do truffle compile/migrate.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, turned out running `truffle compile` didn't do anything because of some permission errors. Running it with sudo worked just fine

Use : `sudo truffle compile`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I would run the command
`truffle init` and that would run fine. When I tried to run `truffle test` nothing would happen. No errors, no output, no timeout, just nothing. If I ran `sudo truffle test` it would work. In the end, I managed to get the tests to run by compiling for the first time. The commands I used where

`truffle init`
`truffle compile`
`truffle test`

I only needed to run the compile the very first time. After that everything worked and I could just run `truffle test` I have no idea why this worked, as the test command does a compile before running the tests.

Hope it helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because [I didn't have any networks defined in truffle-config.js](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1976)

Once I explicitly added the `development` network, `truffle test` began to work.

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same for me using

```
sudo truffle test
```

made everything work!